# What is the best way to set a Firebase Crash user identifier in a widget?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I have been using Crashlytics quite a lot, but now I'm trying out Firebase Crash in an app.

**I would like to set some kind of user identifier** to be able to cross check reports sent by users themselves and crash reports.

In Crashlytics I have always used `Crashlytics.setUserIdentifier()` (https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html?identifier#user-information ).

As far as I can see I have to use `FirebaseCrash.log()` (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#create_custom_logs ), **but** that won't set the identifier one time, right? I suppose it will log it every time I call that method.

That leads me to the real question. **The app is a widget with a service that runs relatively often without the user needing to access an activity. What will be the best place to do that logging?**

Using Crashlytics I have set the user identifier either in the main activity or in a class extending `Application`. Doing the last of the two with Firebase Crash seems to trigger [a known issue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues).

Comment: That's actually the feature that makes me stay with Crashlytics for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to uniquely identify a user in a crash report.  We are considering ways to be able to do this without compromising the privacy of the individual user, which is very important to us.

Comment: Thanks. My suggestion is that the Firebase API could have a method for generating and getting such a (pseudo) random user/installation ID and encourage the use of that. That will probably be good enough for most use cases and "not contain information that personally identifies an individual to Google".